# How can I use the Newsapp twice?

Tags: 2sxc

The 2SXC News app is awesome. I added some fields and entities succesfully.
But this grows in a way it gets a bit messy for the editor, so I want to start another app, based on the same NewsApp. 
Can this be done? If so, how?

Of course, I tried importing again but that doesn't work. When importing it asks 'new folder?' which I confirm but that still throws errors.

If I import an existing app and it  asks 'new folder', I hoped it would create an app with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So importing the same app twice is supported - and it should just create a new folder, put stuff there and get going. If you think it's a bug, please post an issue with details or video or something so we can fix it.

Comment: The 9.32.1 version did not work properly but the 9.43 works just fine. Thnx!